# Filling in an array using a delimiter in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text document separated by tabs.  Each line has the same type of information repeated.  When I use hasNextLine() and a counter to count the lines it only counts a portion of the lines.  I can still create Arrays of the size of the counter I do get.  When I use a for loop to fill the Arrays in the results are unexpected.

Here is a summary of what I did.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
                int lines = 0;
                input.nextLine(); //for the header of the table
                while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                    lines++;
                    input.nextLine();
                }
                System.out.println(lines);//here I don't get the total amount
                String[] colors = new String[lines];
                int[] number = new int[lines];
                fillArray(colors, number);
                System.out.println(colors[i] + i);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        public static void fillArray(String[] color, int[] numbers) {
            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
                input.nextLine(); //for table header
                input.useDelimiter("\\t");
                for(int i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
                    color[i] = input.next();
                    input.next(); //info i'm not using
                    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
                    input.nextLine(); //consumes '\n'
                }
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             }
         }
    }
```

it compiles but my results look like this:

null\n
yellow0\n
null1\n
null2\n
null3\n
etc.

it also shows the correct color and number; but only for one line.

Any help would be appreciated.  I haven't used useDelimiter much but from what I understand it will make '\t' separate tokens instead of white space and '\n'

Answer (score 1):

Don't get bothered, use that:

```
final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The number of lines read is then as easy as `lines.size()`, and you just have to walk the list in order to treat your lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may use OpenCSV http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#custom-sepators. IT is really easy to implement a CSV Reader program using it.